# Javascript button connection

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, var

I am trying to make it where if you click on the button, then bestPlayer.available becomes false, and picked = true. The screen would display names, but then once you pick the top one by clicking on the button, it should disappear, and a new one should come into the list(there are seven players on the list). Here is the code that I tried. Please help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>The Draft</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Draft Stylesheet.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <table id="players">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th id="rtgH">RTG</th>
                        <th id="nameH">Player Name</th>
                        <th id="ovrH">OVR</th>
                        <th id="posH">POS</th>
                        <th id="choose">Draft</th>
                    </tr>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td id="p1">Player</td>
                        <td id="p1ovr">99</td>
                        <td id="p1pos">PO</td>
                        <td> <input type="button" onclick="bestPlayer.available = false; picked=true;" value = "draft"> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td id="p2">Player</td>
                        <td id="p2ovr">99</td>
                        <td id="p2pos">PO</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td id="p3">Player</td>
                        <td id="p3ovr">99</td>
                        <td id="p3pos">PO</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td id="p4">Player</td>
                        <td id="p4ovr">99</td>
                        <td id="p4pos">PO</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td id="p5">Player</td>
                        <td id="p5ovr">99</td>
                        <td id="p5pos">PO</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td id="p6">Player</td>
                        <td id="p6ovr">99</td>
                        <td id="p6pos">PO</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td id="p7">Player</td>
                        <td id="p7ovr">99</td>
                        <td id="p7pos">PO</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
        <script>
            var picked = false;
            var round = 1;
            var pick = 1;
            var first = true;
            function comp(b, a) {
             return a.overall - b.overall;
            }
            var players = [{
              name: "Pat Moran",
              overall: 67,
              position: "AP",
              available: true
            }, {
              name: "Peter Webb",
              overall: 81,
              position: "AP",
              available: true
            }, {
              name: "Ramiro Ramirez",
              overall: 74,
              position: "AP",
              available: true
            }, {
              name: "Manuel Knight",
              overall: 68,
              position: "RP",
              available: true
            }, {
              name: "Allan Alexander",
              overall: 71,
              position: "RP",
              available: true
            }, {
              name: "Gerald Bowman",
              overall: 81,
              position: "RP",
              available: false
            }, {
              name: "Owen Day",
              overall: 78,
              position: 3,
              available: true
            }, {
              name: "Jean Ford",
              overall: 70,
              position: 3,
              available: false
            }, {
              name: "Guy Curtis",
              overall: 59,
              position: 3,
              available: true
            }, {
              name: "Dallas Diaz",
              overall: 68,
              position: 4,
              available: false
            }, {
              name: "Jesus Brooks",
              overall: 70,
              position: 4,
              available: true
            }, {
              name: "Todd Beck",
              overall: 76,
              position: 4,
              available: false
            }, {
              name: "Steve Cortez",
              overall: 66,
              position: 5,
              available: true
            }, {
              name: "Toby Caldwell",
              overall: 64,
              position: 5,
              available: false
            }, {
              name: "Seth Bradley",
              overall: 73,
              position: 5,
              available: true
            }, {
              name: "Lawrence McCarthy",
              overall: 67,
              position: 6,
              available: false
            }, {
              name: "Gerardo Marsh",
              overall: 77,
              position: 6,
              available: true
            }, {
              name: "Alvin Nash",
              overall: 78,
              position: 6,
              available: false
            }];

            function checkAvailabilty(obj) {
                return !!obj.available;
            }

            var findBestPlayer = (function(arr) {
              // a copy of the original data is made.
              var data = arr.slice(0);
              // sort the data with a comparator function
              data.sort(comp);
              // filter out the unavailable players.
              data = data.filter(checkAvailabilty);
              return function(index) {
                return data[index];
              }
            })(players);

            if(picked === true || first === true) {
                bestPlayer = findBestPlayer(0);
                bestPlayerTwo = findBestPlayer(1);
                bestPlayerThree = findBestPlayer(2);
                bestPlayerFour = findBestPlayer(3);
                bestPlayerFive = findBestPlayer(4);
                bestPlayerSix = findBestPlayer(5);
                bestPlayerSeven = findBestPlayer(6);
                first = false;
                picked = false;
            }

            document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = bestPlayer.name;
            document.getElementById("p1ovr").innerHTML = bestPlayer.overall;
            document.getElementById("p1pos").innerHTML = bestPlayer.position;
            document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = bestPlayerTwo.name;
            document.getElementById("p2ovr").innerHTML = bestPlayerTwo.overall;
            document.getElementById("p2pos").innerHTML = bestPlayerTwo.position;
            document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = bestPlayerThree.name;
            document.getElementById("p3ovr").innerHTML = bestPlayerThree.overall;
            document.getElementById("p3pos").innerHTML = bestPlayerThree.position;
            document.getElementById("p4").innerHTML = bestPlayerFour.name;
            document.getElementById("p4ovr").innerHTML = bestPlayerFour.overall;
            document.getElementById("p4pos").innerHTML = bestPlayerFour.position;
            document.getElementById("p5").innerHTML = bestPlayerFive.name;
            document.getElementById("p5ovr").innerHTML = bestPlayerFive.overall;
            document.getElementById("p5pos").innerHTML = bestPlayerFive.position;
            document.getElementById("p6").innerHTML = bestPlayerSix.name;
            document.getElementById("p6ovr").innerHTML = bestPlayerSix.overall;
            document.getElementById("p6pos").innerHTML = bestPlayerSix.position;
            document.getElementById("p7").innerHTML = bestPlayerSeven.name;
            document.getElementById("p7ovr").innerHTML = bestPlayerSeven.overall;
            document.getElementById("p7pos").innerHTML = bestPlayerSeven.position;
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong. When I click the draft button, nothing happens. There are no errors in the console either.

Comment: could you please convert this code to a jsfiddle to aid us in aiding you?

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand that the javascript code runs only once on page load unless you invoke it.
So you will just have to move the code used to set the table values into a function and trigger it onClick.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>The Draft</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Draft Stylesheet.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <table id="players">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th id="rtgH">RTG</th>
                        <th id="nameH">Player Name</th>
                        <th id="ovrH">OVR</th>
                        <th id="posH">POS</th>
                        <th id="choose">Draft</th>
                    </tr>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td id="p1">Player</td>
                        <td id="p1ovr">99</td>
                        <td id="p1pos">PO</td>
                        <td> <input type="button" onclick="bestPlayer.available = false; picked=true;refresh();" value = "draft"> </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td id="p2">Player</td>
                        <td id="p2ovr">99</td>
                        <td id="p2pos">PO</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td id="p3">Player</td>
                        <td id="p3ovr">99</td>
                        <td id="p3pos">PO</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>4</td>
                        <td id="p4">Player</td>
                        <td id="p4ovr">99</td>
                        <td id="p4pos">PO</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>5</td>
                        <td id="p5">Player</td>
                        <td id="p5ovr">99</td>
                        <td id="p5pos">PO</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>6</td>
                        <td id="p6">Player</td>
                        <td id="p6ovr">99</td>
                        <td id="p6pos">PO</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>7</td>
                        <td id="p7">Player</td>
                        <td id="p7ovr">99</td>
                        <td id="p7pos">PO</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                </thead>
            </table>
        </div>
        <script>
  
            var picked = false;
            var round = 1;
            var pick = 1;
            var first = true;
            function comp(b, a) {
             return a.overall - b.overall;
            }
            var players = [{
              name: "Pat Moran",
              overall: 67,
              position: "AP",
              available: true
            }, {
              name: "Peter Webb",
              overall: 81,
              position: "AP",
              available: true
            }, {
              name: "Ramiro Ramirez",
              overall: 74,
              position: "AP",
              available: true
            }, {
              name: "Manuel Knight",
              overall: 68,
              position: "RP",
              available: true
            }, {
              name: "Allan Alexander",
              overall: 71,
              position: "RP",
              available: true
            }, {
              name: "Gerald Bowman",
              overall: 81,
              position: "RP",
              available: false
            }, {
              name: "Owen Day",
              overall: 78,
              position: 3,
              available: true
            }, {
              name: "Jean Ford",
              overall: 70,
              position: 3,
              available: false
            }, {
              name: "Guy Curtis",
              overall: 59,
              position: 3,
              available: true
            }, {
              name: "Dallas Diaz",
              overall: 68,
              position: 4,
              available: false
            }, {
              name: "Jesus Brooks",
              overall: 70,
              position: 4,
              available: true
            }, {
              name: "Todd Beck",
              overall: 76,
              position: 4,
              available: false
            }, {
              name: "Steve Cortez",
              overall: 66,
              position: 5,
              available: true
            }, {
              name: "Toby Caldwell",
              overall: 64,
              position: 5,
              available: false
            }, {
              name: "Seth Bradley",
              overall: 73,
              position: 5,
              available: true
            }, {
              name: "Lawrence McCarthy",
              overall: 67,
              position: 6,
              available: false
            }, {
              name: "Gerardo Marsh",
              overall: 77,
              position: 6,
              available: true
            }, {
              name: "Alvin Nash",
              overall: 78,
              position: 6,
              available: false
            }];

            function checkAvailabilty(obj) {
                return !!obj.available;
            }

            

   function refresh()
  {
  var findBestPlayer = (function(arr) {
              // a copy of the original data is made.
              var data = arr.slice(0);
              // sort the data with a comparator function
              data.sort(comp);
              // filter out the unavailable players.
              data = data.filter(checkAvailabilty);
              return function(index) {
                return data[index];
              }
            })(players);
   
            if(picked === true || first === true) {
                bestPlayer = findBestPlayer(0);
                bestPlayerTwo = findBestPlayer(1);
                bestPlayerThree = findBestPlayer(2);
                bestPlayerFour = findBestPlayer(3);
                bestPlayerFive = findBestPlayer(4);
                bestPlayerSix = findBestPlayer(5);
                bestPlayerSeven = findBestPlayer(6);
                first = false;
                picked = false;
            }

            document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = bestPlayer.name;
            document.getElementById("p1ovr").innerHTML = bestPlayer.overall;
            document.getElementById("p1pos").innerHTML = bestPlayer.position;
            document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = bestPlayerTwo.name;
            document.getElementById("p2ovr").innerHTML = bestPlayerTwo.overall;
            document.getElementById("p2pos").innerHTML = bestPlayerTwo.position;
            document.getElementById("p3").innerHTML = bestPlayerThree.name;
            document.getElementById("p3ovr").innerHTML = bestPlayerThree.overall;
            document.getElementById("p3pos").innerHTML = bestPlayerThree.position;
            document.getElementById("p4").innerHTML = bestPlayerFour.name;
            document.getElementById("p4ovr").innerHTML = bestPlayerFour.overall;
            document.getElementById("p4pos").innerHTML = bestPlayerFour.position;
            document.getElementById("p5").innerHTML = bestPlayerFive.name;
            document.getElementById("p5ovr").innerHTML = bestPlayerFive.overall;
            document.getElementById("p5pos").innerHTML = bestPlayerFive.position;
            document.getElementById("p6").innerHTML = bestPlayerSix.name;
            document.getElementById("p6ovr").innerHTML = bestPlayerSix.overall;
            document.getElementById("p6pos").innerHTML = bestPlayerSix.position;
            document.getElementById("p7").innerHTML = bestPlayerSeven.name;
            document.getElementById("p7ovr").innerHTML = bestPlayerSeven.overall;
            document.getElementById("p7pos").innerHTML = bestPlayerSeven.position;
   }
   refresh();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just realized that this does not work for ties. Do you think you could edit it, so that is two players were tied, they would both show up, one after the other?

Comment: @DallasWhite seriouly?you didn't know the concept ...I helped you with it...I'am not helping you with such trivial logic...figure it out on your own ...it will help in the long run